# test rest api with multiple calls

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

I tried to create an app which would create 100 separate threads and each one will call a REST service in order to measure the performance of it. This is sample code, but I dont get any results in my console :/ What may be wrong with that?

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var slim = new ManualResetEventSlim();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

                        using (var client = new HttpClient())
                        {
                            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sampleRest.com/");
                            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("test").Result;
                            watch.Stop();
                            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Time: {0}\tStatusCode: {1}\tResponseTime [ms]: {2}\tTaskID: {3}", DateTime.Now, response.StatusCode, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds, Task.CurrentId));
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            slim.Wait(new CancellationToken());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [`Jmeter`](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which is used to load testing of API's and Web Pages. Navigate to the shared link, go through the video tutorials available on Youtube. You will be able to start with.

Jmeter gives you the option to add number of threads you want to hit the api at a time and gives lots of features to analyze the output.